# Dropzone error messages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropzone.js

Using ASP.NET MVC, I return an error, when the submitted app/form is missing something, I get a nice red **"X"** on the dropzone file, but the error message is **"[object Object]"**:

**My Controller:**

```
        if (some error)
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Response.StatusDescription = "Internal Error";
            return Json(new { Message = "Missing Something", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
        }
```

**My Javascript:**

```
<script>
    //File Upload response from the server
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        maxFilesize: 20,
        init: function() {
            this.on("complete", function(data) {
              // ???????  var res =  data.xhr.responseText ;
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
<script>
    //File Upload response from the server
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        maxFilesize: 20,
        init: function() {
            this.on("error", function(data, errorMessage, xhr) {
                $(".alertError").show();
                $(".alertSuccess").hide();
                $(".errMessage").text(errorMessage.Message);
            });

            this.on("processing", function(data) {
                $(".alertError").hide();
                $(".alertSuccess").hide();
            });


            this.on("success", function (data) {
                $(".alertError").hide();
                $(".alertSuccess").show();
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: with this I now get to work the red X, but I still get message [object Object], did you change the json in return?